# Graph returned an error: (#100) source is not properly formatted for uploading with image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have code for uploading image using SDK v4 to post on fb timeline

```
$linkData = [
 // 'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/img/about_two.jpg'),
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $linkData, 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

I got error msg 'Graph returned an error: (#100) source is not properly formatted'. I tried with live link for the image path,set image size to 200 X 00. But again shows same error.

Anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: Your image path is most likely wrong – with a leading slash, it refers to the server’s root directory, and I doubt that your image is really located there. Be aware this is a file system path, not a URL.